# How to test if a web-services client application supports TLS?

Tags: ssl, https, tls

I have a client app that accesses an HTTPS web-service. It uses an external library for SSL support.

The service provider has advised they are dropping SSL 3 support and, from a specific date, will only support TLS 1.0 (or later) connections.

I can configure the client to, for example, access a test web-server on my PC (or a Linux server) using an HTTPS GET request.

How can I set up a test service, using something like Apache, or maybe Perl, to positively test whether the client supports TLS 1.0 or later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not yet found a solution along the lines I was looking for. However there are online web-sites that report what level of SSL your client supports.

One (there may be others, I am not endorsing this one) is howsmyssl.com whose reports are like this:

> ### Your SSL client is Bad.
>
> #### Version: Good
>
> Your client is using TLS 1.2, the most modern version of the encryption protocol. It gives you access to the fastest, most secure encryption possible on the web.
>   ...
>
> #### Insecure Cipher Suites: Bad
>
> Your client supports cipher suites that are known to be insecure:
>   ...

Which, in this case, shows that my client software supports >= TLS 1.0 and is not restricted to <= SSL 3

I'm posting this answer on the off-chance that someone else might, now or in future find it useful to verify protocol levels.

---

Footnote: See [malgassar's later answer](https://superuser.com/a/1272455/52492) for a link to GitHub source code in Go language that could be used to implement a local test server along the lines I was originally looking for.

Comment: I check is always useful :) Is there any specific reason why you didn't put a followable link for [howsmyssl.com](https://howsmyssl.com)?

Answer (score 1):

It might not have been available at the time the original post was made back in 2015, but the website that you mentioned (howsmyssl.com) provides an API in the form of a REST service link (https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/api.html) that you can use with any client code (for example a c# .NET windows application in my case) through a web request. You can also type in the link in your browser and look at the returned result after submitting the request within your browser.

Comment: Thanks, +1. The link leads to a page that has links to their open-source code on GitHub. So it is feasible to run this locally. Happy coincidence that it is written in Go (golang) which I am using for a different project.